# Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND redis-server

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu, redis

Dockerfile

```sh
FROM node:alpine    
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install 
COPY ./ ./
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  redis-server:
   image: 'redis'
   ports:
     - "6379:6379"
  node-app:
   build: .
   ports:
     - "8081:8081"
```

app.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const redis = require('redis');
const app = express();
const client = redis.createClient({ host:'redis-server', port: 6379 });
client.set('visits', 0);
app.get('/', (req, res) => { client.get('visits', (err, visits) => { res.send('Number of visits is ' + visits); client.set('visits', parseInt(visits) + 1); }); });
app.listen(8081, () => { console.log('Listening on port 8081'); });
```

Error

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND redis-server
```

Docker Image creation and running continer steps

```
############################ 
Image ID - f419c79d6ce7 
Image Name - myapp

Image ID - 739b59b96069 
Image Name - redis 
#############################

docker run -d --net "redis" --name redis redis 
docker run -d -p 8081:8081 myapp 
######### --------------error ----------------########
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND redis-server
```

Comment: How are you starting the container(s)?  With plain `docker run`, are they both on the same `--net`?

Comment: ############################ 
Image ID - f419c79d6ce7
 
Image Name - myapp 

Image ID - 739b59b96069
Image Name - redis 

#############################

 docker run -d --net "redis" --name redis redis 
 docker run -d -p 8081:8081 myapp 

######### --------------error ----------------########

 Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND redis-server

Comment: The error message indicates that it can't resolve `redis-server`. Nothing here seems to tell it the address so that would seem like an unsurprising error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the error is related to the question. But to answer the title specifically, you can use `image` with `build` and it'll be used to tag built image. In your case:

```yaml
ersion: '3'
services:
  redis-server:
    image: 'redis'
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  node-app:
    build: .
    image: 'myapp'
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
```

You can also add tag aas with usual `image` attribute. Like `myapp:v1`.

For the error itself, it's due to the images being in the different networks.