# How to fix "Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND redis" on docker?

Tags: docker-compose, redis, nestjs

I am using `Redis` using `NestJS` and I see following error. I am going through different articles like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67245653/error-getaddrinfo-enotfound-redis-server) and looks like I am following the same but still getting this error.

Steps:

- I used `docker compose up` command
- Made sure that host in `redis.module.ts` is same as service name in `docker-compose.yml` which is `redis`.

What am I missing here?

Error:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND redis

    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26)
```

Code:

redis.module.ts

```
import { CacheModule, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { RedisService } from './redis.service';
import * as redisStore from 'cache-manager-redis-store';
import { envVariables } from '../env.variables';

@Module({
  imports: [
    CacheModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        store: redisStore,
        host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
        port: configService.get('REDIS_PORT'),
        ttl: configService.get('CACHE_TTL'),
        max: configService.get('MAX_ITEM_IN_CACHE'),
      }),
    }),
  ],
  providers: [RedisService],
  exports: [RedisService],
})
export class RedisModule {}
```

.env

```
#REDIS
REDIS_HOST=redis
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  partnersusers:
    image: partnersusers
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    environment:
      - RUN_ENV=dev
      - NODE_ENV=development
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    networks:
      - default
  redis:
    image: 'redis:alpine'
    ports:
     - "6379:4000"
networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

Error in Docker:

[image]

Comment: network bridge to blame, maybe?

Comment: I honestly don't know

Comment: Maybe, for some reason, `process.env.REDIS_HOST` in `redis.module.ts` is undefined. Did you check with this?

Comment: That value is not undefined (second bullet point under steps in my question).

Comment: @GThree Did you find an answer? I'm having the exact same issue

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert, but I notice a couple of things on your `docker-compose.yml` file.

First your redis service is missing the network assignation:

```
networks:
    - default
```

Without this, redis-commander won't be able to find it as it's not on the same network.

Second redis by default runs on port: `6379` if you want it to run on port `4000` I believe you will need to specify an env var for it.
Or here maybe you just confused the order of the port matching which should've been: `4000:6379` (host_port:container_port).

this is my working `docker-compose.yml` for reference:

```
---
version: '3.8'
services:
    ...
    redis:
        image: redis
        container_name: redis
        hostname: redis
        environment:
            - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
        ports:
            - '6379:6379'
        networks:
            - my-net

    redis-commander:
        depends_on:
            - redis
        container_name: redis-commander
        hostname: redis-commander
        image: rediscommander/redis-commander:latest
        restart: always
        environment:
            - REDIS_HOSTS=local:redis:6379 # note: this has to be the port the redis container exposes.
        ports:
            - "8081:8081"
        networks:
            - my-net

networks:
    my-net:
```

Hope this helps :)